# Why is the input value of the new object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, undefined, user-input

I want to get the values in the form inputs and create a new song object inside the "songs" array.
I am trying to make a music app just for fun, but I got stuck.
Here is my HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="music.app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="music.app.try.css">
    <title>Music App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="add-song-continer" id="add-song-continer">
        <form id="add-song-form">
          <button class="close-btn" id="close-add-song">X</button>
          <h1 class="h1-add-Song" >Add your song </h1>
          <br>
          <input type="text" class="song-name-add" placeholder="Song Name" value=""><br>
          <br>
          <input type="text" class="artist-name-add" placeholder="Artist Name"><br>
          <br>
          <input type="text" class="albom-name-add" placeholder="Albom Name"><br>
          <br>
          <input type="text" class="mp3-file-add" placeholder="Song File"><br>
          <br>
          <input type="text" class="img-add" placeholder="Image"><br>
          <button class="add-song-btn" id = "add-song-btn"> Add Song</button>
        </form>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS code

```css
.add-song-continer {
    margin:0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    top:20%;
    left:50%;
    width:45%;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 460px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0.5rem 1rem 2rem grey ;
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(00%)
    }

.add-song-continer input{
    margin-left: 2.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: rgb(241, 239, 239);
    border: 1px solid gray;
   }
.add-song-continer label{
    margin: 2.5rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
   }
.add-song-continer  h1{
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
   }
   .add-song-btn{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    padding: 0.4rem;
    left: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%);
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    animation: grediant-add-song 0.7s ease-out 0s infinite ;
   }

.close-btn {
    margin: 2%;
    margin-top: -4%;
    padding: 0.4rem 0.4rem;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: tomato;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 1 1 1 gray;
   }



@keyframes grediant-add-song {
    0% {background: linear-gradient(to right, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%)}
    12.5% {background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%)}
    25% {background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%)}
    37.5% {background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%)}
    50% {background: linear-gradient(to left, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%)}
    62.5% {background: linear-gradient(to left top, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%)}
    75% {background: linear-gradient(to top, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%)}
    87.5% {background: linear-gradient(to top right, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%)}
    100% {background: linear-gradient(to right, #66ccff 0%, #cc99ff 100%)}
   }
```

Here is the JavaScript code

```js
let songs = [];

const AddSongFunction = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();

   let song = { 
      name: document.getElementsByClassName("song-name-add").value, 
      artist: document.getElementsByClassName("artist-name-add").value,
      albom: document.getElementsByClassName("albom-name-add").value,
      fill: document.getElementsByClassName("mp3-file-add").value,
      img: document.getElementsByClassName("img-add").value
      };
      
  songs.push(song);
  document.querySelector("form").reset();

    console.log(songs);
    }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("add-song-btn").addEventListener("click", AddSongFunction )
  });
```

I just can't figure It Out, if someone can show what went wrong I will be grateful.
P.S. it is my first question so I hope it's understandable.
Thank you all (:

Comment: If there is only one of each, use an id, not a class name, and document.getElementById not getElementsByClassName. Class name will return a collection, and will not have .value - you would need to reference one of them, perhaps with [0] - for example `document.getElementsByClassName("song-name-add")[0].value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `document.querySelector()` instead of document.getElementsByClassName(). *`querySelector().value`* returns the value of the input box, while *`getElementsByClassName()`* returns collection just like an array. You can in your case use *`getElementsByClassName().value[0]`* but better is to use `querySelector()` only.

Here is the updated song object:

```
   let song = {
      name: document.querySelector(".song-name-add").value,
      artist: document.querySelector(".artist-name-add").value,
      albom: document.querySelector(".albom-name-add").value,
      fill: document.querySelector(".mp3-file-add").value,
      img: document.querySelector(".img-add").value,
    };
```

**One quick Tip:** Avoid using `script` tag in the `head` because is blocking the HTML to load until all the script loads.

```
<script src="music.app.js"></script>
```

Either put it above the closing `</body>` tag, or use `async` property in the script tag used in the `<head>` element.

```
<script async src="music.app.js"></script>
```

It makes your script non-blocking

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i think it will help me in the future

Comment: My Pleasure ! Do vote and accept the answer if you found it helpful for other developers to benefit from this

Answer (score 0):

That's because getElementsByClassName return's a HTMLCollection, the "value" property can be obtained only on a HTMLElement. So you can select an element by it's position on that collection like:

```
let song = { 
      name: document.getElementsByClassName("song-name-add")[0].value, 
      artist: document.getElementsByClassName("artist-name-add")[0].value,
      albom: document.getElementsByClassName("albom-name-add")[0].value,
      fill: document.getElementsByClassName("mp3-file-add")[0].value,
      img: document.getElementsByClassName("img-add")[0].value
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns an array:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("song-name-add");
```

This is because classes are expected to be reusable. If you want this to return a specific value try using

```
<input type="text" id="song-name-add" placeholder="Song Name">
```

and

```
document.getElementById("song-name-add");
```

Or if you specifically want to use classes, you can get the value of the first object with that class using

```
document.getElementsByClassName("song-name-add")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using getElementsByClassName, its return value is an array.
If you want to access its value, you have to use its index `document.getElementsByClassName("song-name-add")[0].value` or loop on the Array